# Custom text style inside of a table cell

Tags: html, styles, docx, pandoc

While converting `.html` to `.docx` I'm trying to customize text style. It seems that the text is not styled properly when inside a table cell.

This HTML **renders** correctly:

```
<!-- example1.html -->
<div custom-style="Index 5">
  Hello, world!  
</div>
```

```
pandoc --print-default-data-file reference.docx > reference.docx
pandoc --reference-doc reference.docx --standalone --output output_$(date +%s).docx example1.html
```

[image]

This HTML **does not** render correctly:

```
<!-- example2.html -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div custom-style="Index 5">
        Hello, cruel world!
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
pandoc --print-default-data-file reference.docx > reference.docx
pandoc --reference-doc reference.docx --standalone --output output_$(date +%s).docx example2.html
```

[image]

I've located 2 thins that might be related to this:

1. [commit](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/7389919bb491b78373ea2197800988b3a61cf0ce) that has the following to say:

   > ...This change also allows nesting of custom styles; in order to do so, it **removes the default "Compact" style** applied to Plain blocks, **except when inside a table**
2. [comment](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6208#issuecomment-603337571) that has the following to say:

   > ...It would be helpful to generate some tests (e.g. test/tables.native rendered to docx) and do a before/after, **removing the Compact style inside the tables**.

Before filing an issue with pandoc's issue tracker, I'd like to understand if I am missing something. Is there still a way to customize text inside a table cell or prevent a fallback to "Compact" style?

Comment: Looks like a missing feature, raising an issue would be warranted. You could also ask on the pandoc-discuss mailing list, people there know more about docx.

Comment: @tarleb I've filed an issue, thanks https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6670